# How to keep VB script file running even after log-off

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have created a windows batch file that listens to a folder for new files and does some processing of that file on occurrence. I am calling this file from my VBScript for executing in background (Without a command window getting opened).

```
Dim WshShell
Dim obj
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
obj = WshShell.Run("C:\Sample\file.bat", 0) 
set WshShell = Nothing
```

This keeps running until I am logged in. Is there any way that I can keep this script run permanently unless I do a force kill of the process? Please help.

Comment: If you open windows scheduler and create a scheduled task you'll see the "Run whether user is logged on or not" option. The trigger could be "start up". I don't see the point of running your batch file from from VBScript, just run it directly

Comment: VBScript IsNot VB.NET.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yeah My bad. It was a wrong tag

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am not given permissions to schedule a task in server with task scheduler. So thought I would do it through a script.

Comment: Then get the required permissions. A scheduled task is the correct way to go about this.

Comment: Running in a script is not going to elevate your permissions. Sounds like you don't have permissions to do what you want. There's no way around that.